# SQL Server : exploding CSV for SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure as below;

```
id  txtName   intReferences
------------------------------
1   Fred      1,4,6,444,56,43,
2   Sam       5,33,5904,43
3   Tom       1200
4   Samantha  43,44,888,99
```

I'd like to write a T-SQL query to return all the records based on a series of numbers provided.

For example, querying for **43** would return Fred, Sam and Samantha. The catch is, when querying for **3**, it shouldn't return results for Sam or Samantha, given that that isn't the number in its entirety. Looking for a direct and **whole number match**.

The CSV value may end in a comma.

I've tried to use the "IN" statement, but it returns results if any portion of the number exists. Ideally trying to achieve without creating a function given some database restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.intReferences, ',') s
where s.value = '3';
```

Then, fix your data model so your are not storing integer values in strings.  This is bad, bad, bad.  Here are some reasons why:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings (using the correct type).
- SQL Server has lousy string manipulation functions.
- Only one value should be stored in a column.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- Resulting queries cannot be optimized to using indexes or partitions.
- SQL has a great way to store lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - appreciate the prompt response and feedback. Out of curiosity, in a MySQL this is a fairly straight forward process and the "IN" statement accommodates for this well.

In your scenario, is your advice creating a separate table with individual relationships to each underlying record and joining them? 

Surely that's overkill when you could simply CSV the key rows in the secondary table from the primary table and query as above?

Comment: Are you *sure* about MySQL, @g33k84 . Gordon is right about normalising your data though; never store delimited data in an RDBMS.

Comment: @g33k84 . . . An appropriate data model is surely not "overkill".  It is using relational databases correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the best way to accommodate this situation is to have properly normalized data.

Another method for querying the data with the current structure would be to check for comma + (your number) + comma.  Something like this...

```
Declare @Temp Table(id int, txtName varchar(200), intReferences varchar(200))

Insert Into @Temp Values(1,   'Fred',      '1,4,6,444,56,43,')
Insert Into @Temp Values(2,   'Sam',       '5,33,5904,43')
Insert Into @Temp Values(3,   'Tom',       '1200')
Insert Into @Temp Values(4,   'Samantha',  '43,44,888,99')

Select  * 
From    @Temp 
Where   ',' + intReferences + ',' like '%,' + '43' + ',%'

Select  * 
From    @Temp 
Where   ',' + intReferences + ',' like '%,' + '3' + ',%'
```